# What would a macro look like that would save a PDF of a report for each record in a db (in access)?

Tags: ms-access, macros

I'm going to be specific as possible but i apologize if my question comes off as confusing upfront...

In my access db I have 5 Tables that are related through 'RefNum' which is an auto number, and the range of 'RefNum's are 1-2694 (or 2694 records). I created a report that is two pages. When I create a form to print the report it creates one large PDF that is 5388 pages (2 pages for each record). What I WANT it to do is create a PDF of the report for each record, so each file would be a two page report for each record.

While creating each file I want it to rename the file to one its respected attributes.

Example: each PDF file would be re-named to --> StudentID.Term

So I assumed that I could do this by attaching a macro to the button, but due to my lack of experience I am lost.

Could some one help me out with this macro?

Answer (score 0):

Using MS Access 2007 or later you can take advantage of the Where argument of [OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Prior to that, you can change the SQL of the query the report is based on, or use a parameter query. Loop through the relevant recordset to get the ID for the Where statement or the parameter.